# Problem Installing Wine with Invalid Package Signature?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to install wine with `sudo pacman -S wine` but I keep getting an error with a package that says it is corrupt or invalid possibly due to PGP signature.

```
:: Retrieving packages...
 lib32-libpcap-1.10.1-1-x86_64         146.6 KiB   178 KiB/s 00:01 [####################################] 100%
(17/17) checking keys in keyring                                   [####################################] 100%
(17/17) checking package integrity                                 [####################################] 100%
error: lib32-libpcap: signature from "David Runge <dvzrv@archlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/lib32-libpcap-1.10.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] 
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I've tried a few things that don't seem to help it. I installed the archlinux-keychain and have tried refreshing the keys and updating them. I've also tried updating, nothing seems to resolve the issue that I've been able to find. Here's the commands I've used:

```
sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring
sudo pacman-key --init
sudo pacman-key --populate
sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
sudo pacman -Syu
```

Not sure what else to try or if I can get more information, like checking if I have the signature for David Runge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the database was corrupted or something, and the commands I tried doesn't clean it.

Removing `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg` and then running the following fixed the problem:

```
sudo pacman-key --init
sudo pacman-key --populate
```

Comment: You should accept the answer, so the question doesn't show up in the feeds of people looking for unanswered questions.

Comment: @Dommondke yah it won't let me accept, they put a time constraint on it so I can't accept the answer until 3 days have passed since I answered.